# Why would my text file suddenly stop being saved?

Tags: c#, debugging, compact-framework, windows-ce, streamwriter

Mildly chastised here by wiser heads, I switched my calls to MessageBox.Show() to writing lines to a StringBuilder which is later saved to a file, both from the app's custom exception handler:

```
public static void ExceptionHandler(Exception ex, string location)
{
    try
    {
        if (inDebugMode)
        {
            LogMsgs.Append(string.Format("{0}\r\n", ex.Message)); 
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            string timeAsStr = string.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}_{3}.txt", dt.Hour, dt.Minute, dt.Second, dt.Millisecond);
            using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(timeAsStr))
            {
                // If the app crashes, this is how the file is written; if it doesn't, it's written
                // in frmCentral.Form1_Closing()
                file.WriteLine(LogMsgs.ToString());
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Exception: " + ex.Message + "\n\nLocation: " + location, GetFormTitle("CCR: " + ex.GetType().FullName,"",""));
    }
```

(...which is called like this:

```
catch (Exception ex )
{
    CCR.ExceptionHandler(ex, "WriteXML.WriteFile");
    . . .
```

)
...and from the main form's Closed() event:

```
private void frmCentral_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CCR.inDebugMode)
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        string timeAsStr = string.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}_{3}.txt", dt.Hour, dt.Minute, dt.Second, dt.Millisecond);
        using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(timeAsStr))
        {
            // If the app closes normally, this is how the file is written; if it doesn't, 
            // (it crashed) it's written in PDAClient.ExceptionHandler()
            file.WriteLine(CCR.LogMsgs.ToString());
        }
    }
} // frmCentral_Closed
```

This worked just dandy until earlier today. I made no change to that code. But now, whether the code crashes or not (I am able to close it from the main form), the file is not being written (at least not to where it had been written before, namely to the root of the handheld device).

I'm adding suchlike messages:

```
CCR.LogMsgs.Append(string.Format("DBCommand exception: {0}\r\n", ex.Message));
```

..and the inDebugMode boolean is indeed being set to true and nowhere to false:

```
public static bool inDebugMode = true; //TODO: Change this to false before deploying.
```

What could be causing this malevolent omission?

### UPDATE

To answer jp2code:

This is what ExceptionHandler does in its catch block:

```
catch(Exception exc)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Exception Handler generated an exception!\n" + exc.Message + "\n\nCalling Location: " + location, GetFormTitle("CCR: " + exc.GetType().FullName,"",""));
}
```

Note that I didn't write this code and thus I often (usually?) don't know the motivation or mindset behind much of it. It seems spaghettier than an Italienfest to me,  but maybe I'm just not grokking it.

Many things are not what they appear in the code, e.g., void functions which are named as if they are bool functions, and this ExceptionHandler() method which you would think (I would, anyway), that it is a global/catch-all exception handler, but really it has to be explicitly called from catch blocks throughout the code to execute.

Also: I tried to implement the errHndlrLock code, but get compile err msg, "*An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'PDAClient.SSCS.errHndlrLock'*"

### UPDATE 2

Today it's back to working; must have been a memory issue or something similar - although I did perform a warm boot yesterday with no respite. So: it worked, it suddently failed to work, and just as suddenly (overnight), it began to work again.

### UPDATE 3

I think this is a clue to what happened in the case of the incredibly mysteriously disappearing debug log text file. When I opened up the most recent ones today, they are chock full of:

```
StackOverflowException
StackOverflowException
StackOverflowException
StackOverflowException
StackOverflowException
StackOverflowException
StackOverflowException
```

...enough of those, and the whole shebang decided to take a vacation, I reckon. Now, though, it is again on hiatus - this CE jazz is flakier than my grandmother's pie crust.

Comment: Just a wild guess, do you have an OpenFileDialog that changes the current directory without the proper flag to restore it when the dialog close? Add a just one time message box to show the current directory when writing the log `MessageBox.Show(Environment.CurrentDirectory)`

Comment: Have you tried giving a full path instead of just a filename when calling the StreamWriter constructor?

Comment: @Steve - No, no OpenFileDialog().

Comment: @oli_wennell: The handheld doesn't have a "C:\" drive, so I don't know what else to do than what I'm doing; and besides, it was working perfectly until a couple of hours ago, so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: I was thinking putting it somewhere like Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal). If you're just specifying a filename, it will go in whatever the current working directory is, which can change due to things outside of your code's direct control.

Comment: @oli_wennell: In .NET 1.1 (I'm in a virtual time warp), the only members of Environment are OSVersion, TickCount, and Version.

Comment: Are you still running the app from the root of the device? Since the way you are creating the file, it will surely be created in whichever folder you're executing from (unless I misunderstand and this handheld defaults to the root or something).
Also, do you control the LogMsgs class and are you sure that this hasn't ben changed and is not actually working?#

Comment: I repeat myself put a MessageBox to show in which directory you are writing the file. You don't specifiy a path name and it could be different from what you suppose to be

Comment: @Clay Ah ok, didn't realise that, sorry. I guess if you're able to specify any known path that should prove or disprove my idea.

Comment: @StephenByrne: It runs from \Program Files\Bla\, but has always put that file in the root before (now it's nowhere to be seen/found).
As to LogMsgs, this is it: 
public static StringBuilder LogMsgs = new StringBuilder();
It worked until noonish, so I don't know what the heck to think.

Comment: Since the log file isn't being created (I reckon), the following MessageBox.Show() just prior to the file being written (or not) did not show:

MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Writing {0}", timedFileName));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nat could be onto something with that `Flush` call. I gave him a +1 on that.

Another thing that could be happening (that I ran into) is multiple items trying to access your Exception Handler at one time.

Say you are closing your form and there is an Exception being caught in one of your methods. Now you have two (2) routines trying to access your `timeAsStr` file at one time, which can't happen.

A solution to that would be to add a `lock` to your Exception Handler routine:

```
private object errHndlrLock = new Object();

public void ExceptionHandler(Exception ex, string location) {
  lock (errHndlrLock) {
    // continue with your code
  }
}
```

Another thing that comes to mind: I see your Exception Handler code shows part of a `try/catch` block.

**Q. What do you do with the Exception you catch?**

If you are recursively calling the same method, this could be a cause of you losing information.

If you wanted to take a different approach, you could use a `Queue`, defined global to the class, along with your `StreamWriter`:

```
class CCR {

  private Queue<string> m_queue;
  private StreamWriter m_writer;

  public CCR() {
    m_queue = new Queue<string>();
    m_writer = new StreamWriter(string.Format("Log_{0}.txt", DateTime.Now.ToFileTime()));
  }

  public void ExceptionHandler(Exception ex, string location) {
    string item = string.Format("{0:u}: {1}\r\n\t\t{2}", DateTime.Now, location, ex.Message);
    if (ex.InnerException == null) {
      m_queue.Enqueue(item);
    } else {
      m_queue.Enqueue(item + string.Format("\r\n\t\tInner Exception: {0}", ex.InnerException.Message));
    }
    QueueHandler();
  }

  private void QueueHandler() {
    while (0 < m_queue.Count) {
      m_writer.WriteLine(m_queue.Dequeue());
    }
  }

  public void Close() {
    QueueHandler();
    m_writer.Flush();
    m_writer.Close();
    m_writer.Dispose();
  }
```

Just make sure you call `Close()` before your code exits

Comment: See my Update for answers.

Answer (score 2):

I could be wrong, but it looks like your stream buffer isn't being flushed.

Try adding

```
file.Flush();
```

after your calls to writeline. Also, I'm not seeing a place where you explicitly close your stream. It's good practice to do so.

Comment: Pretty sure the StreamWriter will get flushed as it's wrapped in a using block, which will ensure it gets disposed.

Comment: Yeah, the "using" is for that very purpose - no muss, no fuss.

Comment: Not always, oli. I've seen it fail enough times to always flush, regardless.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.autoflush(v=vs.71).aspx  Flushing the stream (i.e. through falling out of a Using block) will not flush the encoder unless a manual flush is called.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/7d949d5c-a41c-4dc7-bbcb-429761f851d1/  For more advice by MVPs stating you should *always* flush the buffer manually.

Comment: Adding the file.Flush() made no difference.

Comment: It wouldn't. Using Reflector, you can see that the implementation of `StreamWriter.Dispose()` calls `Flush()`, and also that `StreamWriter.Close()` simply calls `Dispose()` - which is of course the canonical implementation.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: And StreamWriter.Dispose(), I reckon, is implicitly called by wrapping it all in a "using"?

Comment: @ClayShannon: Yep, it is indeed.